# how to pass the same object one activity to another two different activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to pass the same object from one activity to another two different activities. I use same code for both, but it didn't work for one of them. I use these codes to send bitmap.

```
Intent nIntent = new Intent();
nIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), tag.class);
nIntent.putExtra("bitmap",thumbnail);
startActivity(nIntent);

Intent mIntent = new Intent();
mIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), PictureView.class);
mIntent.putExtra("bitmap",thumbnail);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

I use these codes in the other activities.

```
imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_preview);                           
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)this.getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bitmap");
imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

But one of them it doesn't appear on the imageview.

Comment: Is 'tag' a classname? Which one works and which doesn't?

Comment: which one is not working out of the two?

Comment: I'm gonna guess that the 'tag' class doesn't extend activity.

Comment: tag is a classname. tag is not working but it extends activity.

Comment: do you have tag declared in manifest?  Also, are you checking your inputs? (that is, are you making sure thumbnail is a valid, immutable bitmap?)

Comment: yes i declared in manifest. i think if there is something wrong with inputs, Both classes dont work. Altough i use same code in both classes, the picture does'nt appear on the imageview in tag class.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Parcelable before putting it into extras. I make sure you have the right path to your image:

```
Drawable thumbnail = R.drawable.thumbnail;

Intent mIntent = new Intent();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putParcelable("bitmap", thumbnail);
mIntent.putExtra(b);
mIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), PictureView.class);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

and in the mIntent Activity use this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null){
    Drawable image = b.getParcelable("bitmap");
}
```